# Vim automatic hard wrapping long comments in C++?

Tags: c++, vim, comments, word-wrap

To reproduce my issue:

```
$ vim -u NONE test.cpp
:set nocompatible
:set tw=20
:set fo=croql
```

Now type in the following text:

```
/*
    test test test test test test test test test
*/
```

Notice that there is **no leading asterisk on the line containing the tests**. Vim will insert this by default, remove it.

Vim should be auto-wrapping this, but it doesn't.

How can I make Vim wrap automatically in comments, **and only in comments**? `:set fo+=t` works, but then everything gets wrapped and I do not want automatic hard wrapping for code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With my [OnSyntaxChange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4085), you can change the `'fo'` option value depending on whether the cursor inside a comment or not:

```
call OnSyntaxChange#Install('Comment', '^Comment$', 0, 'a')
autocmd User SyntaxCommentEnterA setlocal fo+=t
autocmd User SyntaxCommentLeaveA setlocal fo-=t
```

[It's also available on GitHub.](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-OnSyntaxChange)

Comment: So, I guess my answer should have started, "Except for using an ingenious plugin, Vim cannot..."

Comment: For those of us using `vim-plug`, here's a Github mirror: https://github.com/vim-scripts/OnSyntaxChange

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but Vim by itself cannot be configured to automatically wrap text in multi-line comments, without some character at the beginning of the line. The 'comments' option controls how Vim recognizes comments for automatic wrapping. Multi-line comments must have a "s", "e", and "m" part in the 'comments' option to be recognized; :help format-comments says: "Three-piece comments must have a middle string because otherwise Vim can't recognize the middle lines."

*Nevertheless*, you can still manually reformat such lines with the <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> operator (shorthand <kbd>g</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>q</kbd> for a single line) and Vim should mostly do what you want. If it is slightly off, you can mess with the 'formatexpr' option.

You're probably better off just using the leading * in multi-line comments, or using //-style comments.

There are plugins available that use syntax-defined regions in clever ways which may allow you to work around these limitations. See Ingo's answer.

Comment: Right. You could define four spaces as a middle string, but that would affect other indented lines as well, so it's not useful.

Comment: @IngoKarkat, @Ben Would it be possible to write an autocommand that executes `:set fo+=t` when the cursor is inside a comment and `:set fo-=t` when outside?

Answer (score 3):

I'm using VIM 8.2 and it CAN wrap comments out of the box.

## Short answer how

```
set tw=80
set fo=croaq
```

Check your `comments` option with `:set comments?`. I must contains `/*`, `*` and `*/` sequences.

## Long answer

You can read details in `:help formatoptions`, `:help fo-table` and `:help comments`.

The `tw=80` option is for limiting line width.

The `formatoptions` uses next flags here:

- The `c` flag is to apply wrapping only for comments
- The `r` and `o` flag is for auto-inserting the comment-leader on new lines (`*` symbol for `/*` styled comment in C-like languages).
- The `a` will auto-format your paragraphs while you are typing.
- The `q` option will handle the comment leader the correct way.

For some types of buffers you can apply formatoptions for all text like next:

```
  "Limit line width for git commit messages to 72 characters
autocmd FileType gitcommit setlocal tw=72
  "Auto format all text for git commit messages and markdown files
autocmd FileType gitcommit,markdown setlocal formatoptions+=t
```

Here

- The `t` flag is to apply wrapping for text (additionally to `c`)

The `comments` option will help vim to detect comments correctly.

Comment: This is great!

The only problem I am running into is while editing a comment line *directly* above non-comment line, it will "join" the non-comment line below into a comment. If there is a blank line separating it, it won't affect the code.

I am using Go and `set comments?` gives: `comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://` if that's of any help. It also happens with JS.

Comment: Side note, how can one make this work with bash? It's `set comments?` gives: `comments=s1:/*,mb:*,ex:*/,://.b:#,:%,:zXCOMM,n:>,fb:-`

Comment: Actually, I removed `a` and it solved it.

Comment: @Tony, generally, I do not use the 'a' option with code-base files (enabled only fo markdown), When I wanted to make vim to atowrap my long comment - I enable it with `fo+=a`, then turns it off `fo-=a`.